# hide query params in address bar - VueJS

Tags: vue-router, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 2 and I'm trying to create a link that should send me to another page. This is what I have:

```
<div v-for="u in myList">
   <router-link :to="'/type/' + u.name"><a>{{u.name}}</a></router-link>
</div>
```

The above piece of code works but now I would like to pass a parameter (`u.weight` for example ) along with this link.
I took a look at query parameters but I don't want the user to see this in the address bar `type/productname/?queryparamshere`.

Is there a way to hide query params, or should I consider another way in order to achieve this?

Comment: You can always use localStorage

Comment: localStorage is a singleton.  A user with multiple windows or tabs will break your assumptions if you try to treat it like query parameters.