# refresh vue page with change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an index page with a typeahead input that stores employee names.  When a name is selected the router pushes a vue into the app div with parameters.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'About', params: { email: item.email } })
```

When that vue loads the mounted method fires and runs a lookup function.  When it is refreshed I have

```
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
     this.getPubsSorted()
                 },
```

When a different name is selected since the vue does not change the mounted method does not fire.  My question is the address bar shows the parameter and it does not change when clicking different names.  Is there a way to hide the parameter that shows in the browser address bar?

```
  http://localhost:8080/about/xxxxxx.yyyyyyy@zzzzzz.edu
```

I've looked at [hide query params in address bar - VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774131/hide-query-params-in-address-bar-vuejs)

but it talks about

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

and I can't figure out how to fire my function on the existing vue.  I've tried setting cookies but that does not trigger anything either.  Thanks

Comment: you want that address should not contain `xxxxxx.yyyyyyy@zzzzzz.edu` for example?

Comment: it shows the real email address and I would like to hide it.  And when the second name is selected the address bar stays with the first email.  Totally confusing

Comment: where do you want exactly the operation to clean the address bar from the old email?

Comment: I created a hack.  I set a cookie with the real email which is the same as the userid and I pass the parameter as the Date.now().  I read the cookie on the vue side but the address bar show http://localhost:8080/about/1545966159597.  The events still fire.  Like I said this is a hack and there should be a "force refresh" or something.  But I'm very new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clean the your address from the old email using the following code :

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("@") > -1) {
  window.history.pushState("", "", "/about");

}
```

put that code whatever you want to clear the email.

Comment: That will work-- I was looking for a VUE.js solution but sometime the answer is right in front of us.  Thanks